# Execute a MSYS2 command from PowerShell with different Credentials

Tags: powershell, credentials, msys2

When I execute `sleep 10s` from `cmd.exe`, it correctly waits 10 seconds:

```
msys2_shell.cmd -defterm -no-start -ucrt64 -c "sleep 10s"
```

When I try to do the same with PowerShell, it works aswell

```
function Execute-MSYS {
  Start-Process-Wait -NoNewWindow -FilePath C:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -ArgumentList '-defterm -no-start -ucrt64 -c "sleep 10s"'
}
```

However when I try to invoke MSYS2 using a different user credentials, because I want to keep the packages owning to a different user, it won't work and immediately closes the window:

```
function Execute-MSYS {
  $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $UserPassword -AsPlainText -Force
  $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $User, $securePassword
  Start-Process -Credential $credential -Wait -NoNewWindow -FilePath C:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -ArgumentList '-defterm -no-start -ucrt64 -c "sleep 10s"'
}
```

However If I replace the `sleep 10s` by `bash`, it works! What's wrong with the sleep in combination with credentials?